# What does the 'enter' sign mean in the Meld tool

Tags: meld

What does the 'enter' sign mean in the meld tool (circled red below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The enter sign in Meld indicates that a new line has been added/removed between the two compared files.

In the case of your example, a second entry for 01.03.2019 and 07.03.2019 are added to the left file, and because these entries are on a new line, Meld shows it has been added